# Unsuccessful unpackaged "forecast"

Tags: r, package, time-series, prediction, failed-installation

I have tried many times to install the package "forecast", but always unsuccessfully. I have the newest version of R.
The strange thing is that the package is successfully unpacked, but the load (through the Library) doesn't work.
This is the error:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rcpp', details:
  call: new_dummyObject(.dummyInstancePointer)
  error: object 'class__dummyInstance' not found
```

In addition:

```
Warning message:
package ‘forecast’ was built under R version 3.1.3 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’
```

Comment: try to install Rcpp package and for this you need to update your R tools

Comment: Even Rcpp package doesn't work because there is a bug in the system. I have tried to change the R version and reloading again the package, but unsuccessfully. I mean: I go to "Tools", then "General Options", then "R version" and finally I change the R version. Consequently, I restart the program and I try again to load the package. But I have ALWAYS the same Error, i.e. "Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/ut2dfu/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/libs/i386/Rcpp.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application."

Comment: the problem came from the Rtools you should verify the version you you have